# The service worker has been registered successfully, but the code in the serviceworker.js file has not been executed

Tags: javascript, vue.js, service-worker

The service worker has been registered successfully(This has been shown in devtools), but the code in the serviceworker.js file has not been executed.

I want to add a servicer worker to my Vue project, using webpack as a build tool.

Some other useful information:

1.Serviceworker.js is used as a separate entry file, ensuring that the file output name is still servicerworker.js (other entry files will be renamed by hash values)

2. Enable service worker over HTTP in chrome(on a specific origin) by using some flags. You can refer to [Command line option for whitelisting specific origins to ease development and testing of websites using Secure Origin only features](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=441605).

   3.WebpackConfig.js: devServer.publicPath is `/static/`

index.html:

```
<script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('/static/serviceworker.js', { 
            scope: '/static/' 
        }).then(function (reg) {
            console.log('Registration succeeded. Scope is ' + reg.scope);
        }).catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Registration failed with ' + error);
        });
    }
</script>
```

serviceworker.js:

```
console.log('Hello from sw.js')
```

expected:

1. I expect the service worker to be registered successfully.
2. The console can print out:

   "Registration succeeded. Scope is myOrigin/static/"

   "Hello from sw.js"

results:

1. Service worker registered successfully from the perspective of dev tools and chrome://serviceworker-internals/(I am sorry that I don't have enough reputation to post pictures, so I will give two links.).

devTool
[image]

chrome://serviceworker-internals/
[image]

2. The console only prints out:

   "Registration succeeded. Scope is myOrigin/static/"

Answer (score 2):

I assume that your serviceworker.js file only contains this much code

```
    console.log('Hello from sw.js');
```

It won't work you need to add a eventlistener in your serviceworker.js and then add the console.log in it.For example

```
    self.addEventListener('fetch',function(event){
       console.log('Hello from sw.js');
    })
```

For reference https://developers.google.com/web/ilt/pwa/introduction-to-service-worker

Comment: Not true in my testing. The consol.log() outside of the event listener is logged.